# How to deal with '/usr/bin/python: No module named pip' when pip is installed?

Tags: pip

I am running 'which pip' or 'pip -V' on MacOS and its giving me the following location:

```
pip 20.2.1 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)
```

However, when I try to do `'python -m pip install --user pygame'` it says `'/usr/bin/python: No module named pip'`

Anyone who has come across this problem know how to resolve this issue?

UPDATE:

When I do 'python3 -m pip install --user pygame' or 'python3 install pygame' the following error comes up:

> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
> command: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3 -u -c
> 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] =
> '"'"'/private/var/folders/g9/77451rtd0vj7grc2_lz66tc80000gn/T/pip-install-6wyn2mh9/pygame/setup.py'"'"';
> **file**='"'"'/private/var/folders/g9/77451rtd0vj7grc2_lz66tc80000gn/T/pip-install-6wyn2mh9/pygame/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize,
> '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',
> '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'
> install --record
> /private/var/folders/g9/77451rtd0vj7grc2_lz66tc80000gn/T/pip-record-yyyazq6a/install-record.txt
> --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/pygame
> cwd: /private/var/folders/g9/77451rtd0vj7grc2_lz66tc80000gn/T/pip-install-6wyn2mh9/pygame/
> Complete output (218 lines):
> .........     ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3 -u -c
> 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] =
> '"'"'/private/var/folders/g9/77451rtd0vj7grc2_lz66tc80000gn/T/pip-install-6wyn2mh9/pygame/setup.py'"'"';
> **file**='"'"'/private/var/folders/g9/77451rtd0vj7grc2_lz66tc80000gn/T/pip-install-6wyn2mh9/pygame/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize,
> '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',
> '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'
> install --record
> /private/var/folders/g9/77451rtd0vj7grc2_lz66tc80000gn/T/pip-record-yyyazq6a/install-record.txt
> --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/pygame
> Check the logs for full command output.

Answer (score -1):

I suppose you are ubuntu or any other Linux distribution. I had faced the same error but it is very easy to combat. Use this command to install pip:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

And then always type pip3 instead of pip. So if you want to install pygame, use this:

```
pip3 install pygame
```

rather than this:

```
pip install pygame
```

Comment: it says, sudo: apt-get: command not found. How do I install the 'apt-get' command?

Comment: I've tried, ' brew install python3-pip' and it gave, 'Error: No available formula for python3-pip'

Comment: I then tried, 'brew install pip' and it gave, 'Error: No available formula for pip
Homebrew provides pip via: `brew install python`. However you will then
have two Pythons installed on your Mac, so alternatively you can:
    'sudo easy_install pip'

Comment: So then I tried, 'sudo easy_install pip'
......Some packages may not be found!
Couldn't find index page for 'pip' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:590) -- Some packages may not be found!
No local packages or download links found for pip
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('pip')